# JavaScript - removeChild() failing some of the time but not always

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a script that removes usernames of bots from the list of viewers on twitch chat.

My code:

```
const bots = ['0_applebadapple_0','bananennanen','commanderroot', 'decafsmurf', 'electricallongboard','electricalskateboard','lanfusion','skinnyseahorse','slocool', 'woppes'] //list to check against
const hide = () =>{
    const buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('chat-viewers-list__button') //gets HTMLCollection of elements
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(buttons, button => {
        if (bots.includes(button.dataset.username)) {
            button.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(button.parentNode)
        }} //runs a for each through the HTMLCollection, remove parent element if username is in list
    )}
hide()
```

Note: I am getting button elements and removing their parent divs.

When tested in a chat with 5 to 7 bots it removes only 3-4 of the matches. I have confirmed that other names are matching successfully (case is not an issue, i removed this code), and fail to execute anything after the removeChild once matched(removed this code).

Any ideas why the removeChild is failing?

Comment: Where's your HTML?

Comment: Try `buttons = Array.from(xxx)` and then loop through it.

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a *live* `HTMLCollection`. It's not static; if the collection of `chat-viewers-list__button` classes in the document changes *while the collection is being iterated over*, it's possible that not every element will have the callback called on it. For example, if the collection starts at length 6, if the line

```
name.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(name.parentNode)
```

runs on the first iteration, and the element is removed, `names` will now no longer be of length 6, but of length 5; the element that used to be at index 1 is now at index 0. Then, your next iteration will check `names[1]` - thereby *skipping* the element that was originally at `names[1]`.

Here's an example. There are 4 elements in the collection originally, but because 2 are removed *while* you're iterating, the callback is only fired twice:

```js
const names = document.getElementsByClassName('chat-viewers-list__button') //gets HTMLCollection of elements
Array.prototype.forEach.call(names, name => {
  console.log('iteration');
  name.remove();
});
```

```html
<div class="chat-viewers-list__button">a</div>
<div class="chat-viewers-list__button">b</div>
<div class="chat-viewers-list__button">c</div>
<div class="chat-viewers-list__button">d</div>
```

The solution is to use `querySelectorAll`, which returns a *static* `NodeList`, which won't change while you're trying to iterate over it:

```js
const names = document.querySelectorAll('.chat-viewers-list__button');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(names, name => {
  console.log('iteration');
  name.remove();
});
```

```html
<div class="chat-viewers-list__button">a</div>
<div class="chat-viewers-list__button">b</div>
<div class="chat-viewers-list__button">c</div>
<div class="chat-viewers-list__button">d</div>
```

The unintuitive *live* nature of `HTMLCollection`s makes them hard to work with, unless you're expecting it already. In almost all cases, it's probably better to use `querySelectorAll`; it's static, it's more flexible (that is, it accepts a *selector string*, which can be anything), and it can be directly iterated over with `forEach` in modern browsers.

It's also a bit less wordy to use `.remove()` rather than `.parentNode.removeChild(button.parentNode)`:

```
const bots = ['0_applebadapple_0', 'bananennanen', 'commanderroot', 'decafsmurf', 'electricallongboard', 'electricalskateboard', 'lanfusion', 'skinnyseahorse', 'slocool', 'woppes'] //list to check against;
const hide = () => {
  const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.chat-viewers-list__button');
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(buttons, button => {
      if (bots.includes(button.dataset.username)) {
        button.parentNode.remove();
      }
    }
  )
}
hide();
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. Using querySelectorAll returned empty. I ended up using Array.from on the HTMLcollection as described in the other comment and got it working,

Comment: Oops, my mistake, need to add the `.` in front of the `qSA` selector string in order to clarify that you want to find a *class*. (A `#` symbol means find the ID, and no symbol at all means find a *tag name*)

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsXXX()` functions return an `HtmlCollection` which is a *live* view of the elements on a page.  `Array.prototype.forEeach.call` is like looping through an array, so as you remove an element, the next element now has that index and the length decreases, but the loop moves to the next index skipping that element ([*fiddle*](https://jsfiddle.net/jgoemat/x261qaLn/2/)):

```
-- removes 1st, 3rd, 5th, 7th, 9th elements
const divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(divs, div => {
  console.log(`divs.length is now ${divs.length}`);
  div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
});
```

If you create a real array first using `Array.from` and loop through that, it should work as expected ([*fiddle*](https://jsfiddle.net/jgoemat/htkubymv/1/)).

```
-- removes as expected
const divs = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('div'));
divs.forEach(div => {
  console.log(`divs.length is now ${divs.length}`);
  div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
});
```